# Extracting a substring from a string and also including 10 characters before and after

Tags: python, regex

I have a string:

```
str = "alskdfj asldfj 1234_important_what_i_need_123 sdlfja faslkdjfsdkf 234234_important_what_i_need_12312 alsdfj asdfj"
```

I want to extract each occurrence of the `"%important_what_i_need%"` bit from the string, including `10` or so characters before and after the search term.

How do I do this with python? Do I need to import re?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with "aaafoobbb" and looking for "foo" and the surrounding two characters on either side, you could do:

```
>>> start_string = "aaafoobbb"
>>> search_string = "foo"
>>> index = start_string.index(search_string)
>>> s[(index - 2) : (index + len(search_string) + 2)]
```

Should be easy enough to adapt to your needs, although you'll need to add some extra checks to make sure your slice indices are within range (e.g. make sure that `index - 2` is not less than 0). You definitely want to become more familiar with [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation) and [strings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) in Python.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I found that the number I substituted for "2" had to not be very large/exceed the total length of start_string. Question: any particular reason you used .index() instead of .find()? .index() raises a ValueError when the substring isn't found...

Comment: It's just what came to mind at the time. Find is fine too, I think. Also, thanks for fixing the variable name. Clearly had not had my coffee yet.